# collectd wrong cpu values

Tags: cpu, cpu-usage, collectd

I'm trying to monitor my cpu usage using collectd, problem is the log files are always giving increasing measurements (starts with 80 and ends in 20k), like it is giving me cumulative values (not sure if they are).

This is my configuration :

```
Interval     0.1

 LoadPlugin cpu

 <Plugin cpu>
     ReportByCpu true
     ReportByState true 
     ValuesPercentage false
 </Plugin>
```

Everything else is set to default. Any ideias ? thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think `ValuesPercentage true` is what you want. It will give you CPU usage in % from 0-100.

```
 <Plugin cpu>
     ReportByCpu true
     ReportByState true 
     ValuesPercentage true
 </Plugin>
```